# How to feed boolean placeholder by means of TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to launch trained in *Keras Tensorflow* graph by means of *Java Tensorflow API*. 
Aside from standard input image placeholder, this graph contains *'keras_learning_phase'* placeholder that is needed to be fed with a *boolean* value.

The thing is, there is no method in [TensorFlowInferenceInterface](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java) for *boolean* values - you can only feed it with **float**, **double**, **int** or **byte** values.

Obviously, when I try to pass **int** to this tensor by means of this code:

```
inferenceInterface.fillNodeInt("keras_learning_phase",  
                               new int[]{1}, new int[]{0});
```

I get

> tensorflow_inference_jni.cc:207 Error during inference: Internal:
>   Output 0 of type int32 does not match declared output type bool for
>   node _recv_keras_learning_phase_0 = _Recvclient_terminated=true,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=4742451733276497694,
>   tensor_name="keras_learning_phase", tensor_type=DT_BOOL,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"

Is there a way to circumvent it? 
Maybe it is possible somehow to explicitly convert **Placeholder** node in graph to **Constant**? 
Or maybe it is possible to initially avoid creation of this **Placeholder** in the graph?

Comment: Post your code where you get this issue

Comment: I have the same problem, and the answer below fix the input feed problem, but in Android, I get another error: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Switch', there is a document said about that, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/#fixing-missing-kernel-errors-on-mobile, but I've no idea about what to do, should I rebuild a custom TensorFlow lib? Do you have the same problem, and how do you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @Piasy I didn't have exactly the same issues, but faced similar a couple of times. For me it helped to update tensorflow lib to current version and rebuild .so libs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` class essentially is a convenience wrapper over the full [TensorFlow Java API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary), which does support boolean values.

You could perhaps add a method to `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` to do what you want. Similar to [`fillNodeInt`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d2fa8eaf544df43492b668c39df6ff32bec25629/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L209), you could add the following (note the caveat that booleans in TensorFlow are represented as one byte):

```
public void fillNodeBool(String inputName, int[] dims, bool[] src) {
  byte[] b = new byte[src.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
    b[i] = src[i] ? 1 : 0;
  }
  addFeed(inputName, Tensor.create(DatType.BOOL, mkDims(dims), ByteBuffer.wrap(b)));
}
```

Hope that helps. If it works, I'd encourage you to contribute back to the TensorFlow codebase.

Comment: Thanks, @ash. I've added this method to the code of inference interface, rebuilt _libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar_ and it worked. A bit later I will commit this to the Tensorflow codebase.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43009151/7005524) by [ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6708503/ash), as the Tensorflow API has changed a little. Using this worked for me:

```
public void feed(String inputName, boolean[] src, long... dims) {
  byte[] b = new byte[src.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    b[i] = src[i] ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;
  }
  addFeed(inputName, Tensor.create(Boolean.class, dims, ByteBuffer.wrap(b)));
}
```